# How to store PhpStorm/WebStorm IDE project settings on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

JetBrains help [says](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/project.html):

> All the settings files in the .idea directory should be put under version
>   control except the workspace.xml, which stores your local preferences. 
>   The workspace.xml file should be marked as ignored by VCS.

But all large GitHub projects exclude `.idea` from version control in `.gitignore`. So what is the right way to store IDE project settings (directories, inspections) on GitHub? It would be nice to see an example of such repository.

Comment: They exclude such files because they following the general idea that code should be independent of the IDE used to developed it. Plus, if it's a open-source or public repository then anyone can use it .. so why do they need your IDE settings if they will use Notepad/vim/etc to edit it (if they need to edit, of course)? Also -- you do not need some IDE settings to actually use that code (to run it).

Comment: All that text above means .. that it only makes sense to keep your IDE settings in the same repository as your code if it's a private project/repository and all of your team members (or at very least majority) are using the same IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/github/gitignore is a collection of `.gitignore` templates, including [template for JetBrains IDEs](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/JetBrains.gitignore). Although this template is not written entirely according to the JetBrains' advice, you can base your work on it.

Meanwhile, there have been a few open pull requests which attempted to fix the `.idea` directory issue ([#1475](https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/1475), [#1399](https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/1399) and [#1509](https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/1509)). You can take check them out as well.

*Update*
[#1475](https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/1475) has been merged.

Comment: For those coming by in the future: all the issues mentioned above have been closed. The later 2 recommend ignoring the whole .idea directory which is not recommended by JetBrains.